# Snackbar Creator class?

Tags: android, class, snackbar

If we are using lots of Snackbars, would it be better to create a class that controls the snackbar creation or would it even slow performance? Because we would be creating one more object for the garbage collector(instance of that creator class).

I'm using such code a lot:

```
 final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Added to favourites", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    snackbar.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                            snackbar.show();
```

or the same but with color options too:

```
        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.color.accentColor));
        snackbar.show();
```

Is it a good idea to create such a class for making those Snackbars or would it just put more weight on the performance?

Now with a helper class, code looks much more readable:

```
SnackBarHelper snackBarHelper = new SnackBarHelper(coordinatorLayout, "You already signed up for this one!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackBarHelper.addColor(R.color.accentColor);
                            snackBarHelper.getMySnackbar().show();
```

This is without the onclick code though.

Comment: how do you set a coordinatorLayout?

Comment: I'm unsure of what your question means. The coordinatorLayout is in xml and I instantiate it with findViewById. If I remember correctly, as I haven't touched this project in over a year :D